# Cassandra equivalent for MySQL's full text search

Tags: mysql, cassandra

We are planning to migrate an application from MySQL to Cassandra. The one major issue we're seeing is that the application makes extensive use of MyISAM's full text search. What can we use an alternative on cassandra?

Answer (score 3):

There is an implementation of [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) in Cassandra: [Solandra](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra).

> Solr (pronounced as /soʊlə/,/soʊlər/, SOH-lər) is an open source
>   enterprise search platform from the Apache Lucene project. Its major
>   features include powerful full-text search, hit highlighting, faceted
>   search, dynamic clustering, database integration, and rich document
>   (e.g., Word, PDF) handling. Providing distributed search and index
>   replication, Solr is highly scalable.[1](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

You can find some other information here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/search/dse_search_about

Comment: Note that while DSE2 search is also based on Solr, it's a more sophisticated design than Solandra.  (DSE2 is the 3rd generation of search systems by Jake Luciani, after Lucandra and Solandra.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra) which runs `Elasticsearch` as a plugin for `Apache Cassandra`.

Some real example of Elassandra can be found in [here](https://medium.com/rahasak/elassandra-936ab46a6516)